# Trouble getting JDBC-River to work with elasticSearch

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

After setting up JDBC River for elasticSearch, the following command:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "mypassword",
        "sql" : "select * from products"
    }
}'
```

gives me this error:

```
{
"error": "UnavailableShardsException[[_river][0] [2] shardIt, [0] active : Timeout waiting for [1m], request: index {[_river][my_jdbc_river][_meta], source[{\n    \"type\" : \"jdbc\",\n    \"jdbc\" : {\n        \"driver\" : \"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\",\n        \"url\" : \"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db\",\n        \"user\" : \"root\",\n        \"password\" : \"mypassword\",\n        \"sql\" : \"select * from products\"\n    }\n}\n]}]",
    "status": 503
}
```

elasticSearch otherwise seems to be running fine. I am able to PUT data and retrieve it using CURL.

When I start EC, I also see that the JDBC River plugin is loaded:

```
[2013-11-01 15:51:42,108][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Marko, Cain] loaded [jdbc-river], sites []
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this is occurring? I am a little stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling elasticSearch, and everything is working fine now. I'm not sure what the problem was, since it was a pretty straightforward setup process.